# facebook and windows desktop applications

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk, desktop-application

Are facebook desktop applications still allowed? I wrote an application but the authentication has stopped working. Before I dig out the source code I thought I would check to see if anything to do with oAuth had been deprecated but I cant even find a mention of desktop apps any more!

Answer (score 0):

Facebook PowerShell Module (http://facebookpsmodule.codeplex.com) is basically a desktop application, and it is working fine. I'm not sure how long it has been since you last used your desktop application -- there were some OAuth changes many months ago, and more recently the OfflineAccess deprecation could be affecting your app. I would need more details on what your app does and what problem you are seeing to answer more definitely.

Comment: This is the auth url: http://www.new.facebook.com/authorize.php?app_id=2442338999&ext_perm=offline_access, but I think the issue is probably that the url is new.facebook.com